# Evaluate cell array using matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have a n by n cell Z where the (i,j) component of Z is an ordered pair (s,t).

I then have some matrix Y. Basically each component of Z contains a coordinate using which I am trying to locate an element of Y. In other words, I am trying to return a n by n matrix X where X(i,j) = Y(s,t).

Here is a specific example:

suppose n = 3,

```
Z = {[1 1] [2 1] [2 2];
     [1 1] [1 3] [3 3];
     [3 2] [3 1] [2 4]}

Y = [1 2 3 5;
     2 3 5 7;
     1 0 4 6]
```

I am trying to get a 3 by 3 matrix that gives, in this example,

```
[1 2 3; 
 1 3 4; 
 0 1 7]
```

I've tried to use Z = squeeze(num2cell(permute(cat(3,A,B),[3,1,2]),1)) to create Z from two other matrices A and B, but I am stuck with the question I have.

Comment: I agree with Daniel, it would be good to have copy-pastable `Z` and `Y`, i.e. with `[1,1]` instead of `(1,1)` and `...` and so on.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
 fun = @(c) Y(c(1), c(2));
 X = cellfun(fun, Z)
```

Comment: Even smaller using `fun = @(c) Y(c);` and so on.  :-)

Comment: @mbschenkel +1 for neatness, although it may not be the fastest approach

Answer (score 3):

```
rc = vertcat(Z{:});
X = reshape(Y(sub2ind(size(Y), rc(:,1), rc(:,2))), size(Z));
```

This may be faster than [@mbschenkel's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22271462/2586922), as it avoids `cellfun`.

Comment: +1 for roughly 5x more performance :)  
(But if speed was really the goal, I would make `Z` a 3x3x2 matrix instead of a cell array s.t. `X = Y(Z);` would do the job.)

Comment: Thank you, Luis. This is helpful! I am running this thing inside of a function that a minimizer lsqnonlin calls. Speed is important for me.

Comment: @lawrence To increase speed, consider using a 3D array instead of a cell array, as mbschenkel suggests. That will make the indexing easier, and with some modifications will avoid the use of `vertcat` in my code